# Combatting ClassNotFoundException after mvn clean using exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to execute Maven functionality new to me.

My goal is to use a class to update a Java project properties file before a Maven build so that the props file is customized to a build type: development, production, etc. Then, build the project.

I'm currently using the `exec-maven-plugin` with somewhat success (I added a class to the project that has access to the properties file. In the pom, that class is referenced in the `exec-maven-plugin` `<plugin>` element as `<mainClass>`).

I am currently able to run the class in the build process where I need by doing `mvn exec:java <phase>`, and that's great, but if I clean the project before running that again, it fails with `ClassNotFoundException`. I think what is happening is that the compiled code is wiped during the clean phase, so java cannot find that code. If I build the project without a clean, everything works. But at some point, I'll need to clean the project.

**QUESTION**: Assuming I'm correct about the `ClassNotFoundException` cause, is there a way to compile *only* my new class beforehand using maven or exclude it from a clean before setting my build-specific properties by running `mvn exec:java` on the project?

I realize I could use `javac` to compile that class as a separate action beforehand, but I'd prefer to make compiling this code part of just one action. And I have looked at multiple posts here, some of which helped me up to this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole approach seems not to be right.

First of all, you should ask yourself if you really need different versions of your artifact for different stages. It is much better to adapt to development, production etc. by reading external properties.

Secondly, if you do need something like this, use a Maven profile that activates or sets special properties.

If you really need more complex logic, write a Maven plugin.

Do not try to run a class of your project to use it in the build.

Comment: Thanks for that. 

"...adapt to development, production etc. by reading external properties"
Sorry if I was not clear. This is what I'm trying to do, but by setting a few build-specific props before hand. What about that is not recommended? 

And by "...artifact for different stages", to be clear on the terminology, you mean artifact as in .war file & stage as in maven phase? I will look into profiles

Comment: I mean that you just build **one** WAR or JAR (not one for development, one for production), and this WAR/JAR reads external properties. So the Maven build process only runs once and you only replace properties in the runtime environment.

Comment: artifacts are WARs, JARs etc., stages are development, production etc.